# How to fetch value from JSON array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a JSON array like below . I need to fetch the value of  all "name " elements in it and concatenate them to a single string.  How can i do that?

Please note that "name " is a child/element of "modifiers" and modifiers is a child/element of "_embedded" and each "modifiers' can be either empty[] or can contain multiple objects each object having "embedded" ,"id", "name" within it.

```
{
"items": [{
    "_embedded": {
        "modifiers": [{
            "_embedded": {
                "modifiers": [{

                    "_embedded": {
                        "modifiers": []
                    },
                    "id": "3145738",
                    "name": "ABCD"
                }]
            },
            "id": "312121738",
            "name": "EFGH"
        }]
    }
}]
}
```

Comment: Did you attempt anything?

Answer (score 2):

A quick way to do this is to `stingify` the object and use positive look behind to get the names :

```js
const obj = {
  "items": [{
    "_embedded": {
      "modifiers": [{
        "_embedded": {
          "modifiers": [{

            "_embedded": {
              "modifiers": []
            },
            "id": "3145738",
            "name": "ABCD"
          }]
        },
        "id": "312121738",
        "name": "EFGH"
      }]
    }
  }]
}

const result = JSON.stringify(obj).match(/(?<=name":")\w+/g).join(',');

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Nice regex, this is a better way \

Answer (score 1):

You can `JSON.stringify` the json and extract names from it:

```js
const data = {
  items: [{
    _embedded: {
      modifiers: [{
        _embedded: {
          modifiers: [{
            _embedded: {
              modifiers: []
            },
            id: "3145738",
            name: "ABCD"
          }]
        },
        id: "312121738",
        name: "EFGH"
      }]
    }
  }]
};


const res = JSON.stringify(data).match(/"name"\:\"\w+\"/g).map(el => el.slice(8, el.length - 1))
console.log(res)
```